# Facebook customer chat plugin not appearing

Tags: facebook

Am trying to implement Facebook customer chat plugin(which is generated by facebook) in JSF project, but when I insert the code snippet ... I don't get anything, no errors, no chat bubble, yet I can see a generated div with it's data

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution="setup_tool"
  page_id="*********"
  theme_color="#44bec7"
  logged_in_greeting="Hello, speak with us"
  logged_out_greeting="Hello, speak with us">
</div>
```

it should be noted that I had to add double quotes for setup_tool as JSF was throwing error  `attribution="setup_tool"`

Answer (score 0):

It's working after adding

```
appId: '*****',
autoLogAppEvents : true
```

to `FB.init`